# What is the traditional exegesis of the Davidic Promise in 2 Samuel 7

Tags: king-david, prophecy

2 Samuel 7 states that Nathan prophesied to David that G-d will establish/confirm his throne through all generations. After the exile in Babylon and the current exile, how did Chazal understand this promise?

Comment: "_2 Samuel 7 states that Nathan prophesied to David that G-d will establish/confirm his throne through all generations._" Do you mean _unconditionally_? G-d had already said to David's son "_**if** you follow My laws and observe My rules and faithfully keep My commandments_, I will fulfill for you the promise that I gave to your father David" ([I Kings 6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Kings.6.12?lang=bi&lang2=en))...

Comment: ...Also, in the Psalms, it says: "The LORD swore to David a firm oath that He will not renounce, 'One of your own issue I will set upon your throne. _**If** your sons keep My covenant
and My decrees that I teach them_, then their sons also, to the end of time, shall sit upon your throne.'" ([Psalms 132](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.132.12?lang=bi&lang2=en)).

Answer (score 2):

Malbim in [his commentary](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.7.16?lang=bi&with=Malbim&lang2=he) says:

> וכן הגם שהכסא יופסק לפעמים בעתי הגליות בכ"ז לא יופסק לעולם...
>
> *(my translation)* and even though the Jewish kingship will be interrupted during the
> times of exile, even so the interruption will not be forever ...

which indicates that the Davidic dynasty will be reestablished after the exiles.

Comment: I don't think the OP had Malbim in mind, when he used the terms "tradition[al] exegesis" and "Chazal", in the question.

Comment: Malbim is Chazal, and if you don't want to use 'Chazal' like that, Malbim _brings_ Chazal, and also brings traditional exegesis?